# C# Set startup form in another form besides main

Tags: c#, forms, object, startup

Is it possible to set the startup form in another cs file besides program.cs from main? 
Code to set a form as startup object in program.cs from main:

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

So for instance, is it possible to set the startup object in Form2, to be Form2, while Form2 is not the startup object (yet hopefully)>?

TO BE SPECIFIC: I wanted to show form2 on startup programmatically, while Form1 was set as startup object. I need to place that code in form2 itself. So I couldn't just simply open Form2 via Form1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Huh? You can only have one entry point/startup object. I don't understand what you are trying to do *or* asking.

Comment: Imagine that Form1 is set as startup object, as usual. Now I have a second Form, which will be shown in a button click event on Form1. How Can I set Form2 as startup object? I know that this is possible with the code: Application.Run(Form2()); Problem: This code needs to be placed in program.cs, while I need a code which can set Form2 as startup object, which I can place in Form2 itself

Comment: You can't. You can only have one startup object. What does that buy you anyways? Are you trying to change the behavior for the next execution of the program?

Comment: I think you understand me wrong, I dont want multiple startup objects, I want to set another form as startup object programmatically. Problem: I would like to have code to set form x as startup object instead of form1, and the code needs to execute properly when placed in form x

Comment: So change the original line to "FormX". In winforms, you start with a Program.cs; you can't do `Application.Run` from within a form, because the form won't exist yet (unless you define a static `Main` method yet), and it doesn't get you anything anyways. Can you explain *why* you want this?

Comment: @LetsCode You are saying a lot of things that seem contradictory. You don't need to muck about with which Form is the startup object if all you're trying to do is make a Button click show a new Form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting startup logic in forms, you probably would be better served by an ApplicationContext.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Instead of launching a form, you create a class with a [STAThread]Main() function and you make that class your startup object. Within that class you can do some setup (for example, verify that key logging capabilities are present) and then

```
//ExampleContext is defined as ExampleContext : ApplicationContext
using (ExampleContext exampleContext = new ExampleContext()) 
{
   Application.Run(exampleContext); //The context handles the login and main forms.
}
```

Inside the application context you can open and close forms freely and you can maintain a global state that will be able to track them. Closing forms won't close your application, allowing you to have multiple forms that appear "top level" to your users.

To exit the application, have your context call `Application.Exit()` instead of closing the "main" form (because there isn't such an animal).

Comment: Thanks, it seems like you are the only one who understands me correclty! Your answer suites my purpose perfectly.

Comment: @LetsCode Glad you found a solution. Could you try and clarify the question itself so others have a chance of finding this?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, Question is edited, do you understand it now? Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @LetsCode Its better, although I wouldn't have come up with Godeke's answer from that problem statement. It sounds like your question is just "Start Muliple Forms at startup" with "Don't close the application just because Form1 closed". Thanks for trying though!

Comment: The only reason I "got it" was that juggling forms was why I first used an ApplicationContext. It turns out it has many, many other reasons to be preferred to a Main Form, but it does this simple job very well.

Comment: Is the `using` necessary? The example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.1#Examples) doesn't wrap in a `using`.

Comment: I tend to be generous with usings as they make it clear I don't want the object to live on beyond the using's scope, but it isn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like what you want to do is just create and show a new Form. All you need to do to do this is put code like this in your Button_Click event:

```
Form2 newForm2 = new Form2();
newForm2.Show();
```

Comment: That code needs to be in Form1's button click event, I would like a code to place in Form2 itself :)

Comment: @LetsCode For the life of me I *cannot* figure out what you are trying to do. At what point in your program's lifetime are you trying to create and show a new Form2? Do you just want your program, when it starts up, to show both a Form1 and a Form2?